# How to simply change text of a label in kivy?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

how do i update text in a label?

```
a=Label(text='60')
self.add_widget(a)
```

whilst the code is running how would i change 60 to another number for example 50.

i have tried to change the text like this:

```
a=Label(text='60')
self.add_widget(a)
time.sleep(5)
a=Label(text='50')
self.add_widget(a)
```

But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates two different Label widgets and adds them to the widget tree. If you want to change a specific property of a previously created widget:

```
# Create Label and reference it to var 'a'
a = Label(text='60')
self.add_widget(a)
time.sleep(5)
# You can use the 'a' var to access the previously created Label
# and modify the text attribute
a.text = '50'
```

EDIT: In order to delay the change of the Label text property, use `Clock` instead of `time` (this last one will freeze your app while the timer finishes)

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

def update_label(label_widget, txt):
     label_widget.text = txt

# Create Label and reference it to var 'a'
a = Label(text='60')
self.add_widget(a)

# In five seconds, the update_label function will be called 
# changing the text property of the 'a' Label to "50"
Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: update_label(a, "50"), 5)
```

EDIT2: Label with countdown

To change you label periodically, you can use `Clock.schedule_interval`

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

def countdown(label_widget):
     # Convert label text to int. Make sure the first value
     # is always compliant
     num = int(label_widget.text)

     # If the counter has not reach 0, continue the countdown
     if num >= 0:
         label_widget.text = str(num - 1)
     # Countdown reached 0, unschedulle this function using the 
     # 'c' variable as a reference 
     else:
         Clock.unschedule(c)

# Create Label and reference it to var 'a'
a = Label(text='60')
self.add_widget(a)

# Every 1 second, call countdown with the Label instance
# provided as an argument
c = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda x: countdown(a), 1)
```

Comment: thanks this was really helpful it works. However it changes the text of the label before the graphical user face has loaded and by the time i get to the screen it has already changes the text. How would i get it to change the text once i am on on the actual screen?

Comment: Ah, yes. That's because of the `time.sleep(5)`. In Kivy, this will freeze your application. If you can to schedule a certain event you should use `Clock` instead. I'll edit with a possible way to do this

Comment: I tried this solution and added `Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: update_label(a, "50"), 5)` and then another `Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: update_label(a, "40"), 5)`. However this just skipped the first line and went straight to displaying 40. How would i solve this. This is so useful.

Comment: That is because you are scheduling both function calls for the same time. you could try `Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: update_label(a, "40"), 8)` for example to schedule the second call for three seconds later. Alternatively, you could add another Clock scheduling inside the update_label function

Comment: so if i was making a 30 seconds countdown timer this way would not work?

Comment: works very well thanks you. This is the first simple answer i have come across.

Comment: Glad I could help. Mark as correct when you have a chance